# Setup in Unit Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, cmd

I'm trying to set up for unit testing using php yet i'm stucked at this note, where i can check if the tests succeeded or not, or is it in process...
so how can I make the ./vendor/bin/phpunit work?

Btw I followed a certain tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQucsmbOkpE @ 5.21.

[image]

Comment: Man on video is running all on MacOS (Vagrant). But you are trying to run it on Windows, obviously that some commands will be unavailable. You should find video how to run it exact on Windows. Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkA1YdZQsWY

Comment: oh i thought the commands would be similar. Thank you : )